# LWC1041: Static id values are not allowed in iterators. Id values must be unique within a template and must therefore be computed with an expression

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am getting this error:

> LWC1041: Static id values are not allowed in iterators. Id values must be unique within a template and must therefore be computed with an expression.

In my **Lightning Web Component**.

I googled and couldnt find anything. Any one has any ideas what that means?

Its related to `for:each` iterator directive:

`<template for:each={WA_ActivitiesData} for:item="activity">
    <div class="activity activity--completed" key={activity.id}>`

Comment: Where does the id related to the activity variable comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of this id attribute on list item was static

```
<li id="activity-1-completed">
```

Comment: LWC doesnt allow to use static id values as an Id inside iterator directive

Comment: Thanks - I've pasted a snippet from lightning design system and it had id hardcoded that is easy to miss.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like we have the whole picture since your code snippet doesn't show the whole iteration, but that error is specific to the LWC compiler which makes sure that the same `id` value is not used in the template because `id` values are expected to be unique.

On a related note, the usage of `id`s in LWC is restricted to accessibility purposes and any JS or CSS selectors that reference `id`s will not work because id values are transformed by the compiler to ensure that they are globally unique. This is hinted at [here](https://lwc.dev/guide/css#css-support-and-performance-impact) and [here](https://lwc.dev/guide/composition#access-elements-the-component-owns) but we could do a better job explaining it. I will open an issue for it.

Comment: yeah, I feel like errors with LWC1041: .... format should have a documentation somewhere. easier to debug and read more